# Using theme color in global theme mixin with ng-deep

Tags: css, angular, sass

I am using the style guidelines specified at https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components

My component has a mat-form-field where I want to change the border color. If I put the ng-deep style in component.scss file, it gets applied aliright, like below:

```
  :host ::ng-deep {
    mat-form-field.active-field .mat-form-field {
      &-flex {
        border: 2px solid red;
      }
    }
  }
```

Now, I want to keep the border color dynamic and dependent on theme. I have a mixin defined in my-component-lib.theme.scss, which gets called from a global theme file of the application. I tried to put the same style inside that mixin as:

```
    @mixin my-component-lib-theme($theme) {
       $primary: map-get($theme, primary);

      .component-container ::ng-deep {
        mat-form-field.active-field .mat-form-field {
          &-flex {
            border: 2px solid lighten(mat-color($primary), 30);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

But it is not working. I have some other styles in the mixin which does not use `ng-deep`, and those styles are working fine. So, it seems the issue here is with `::ng-deep` in global theme mixin. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `::ng-deep` selector is an angular-specific pseudo-class, which tells the Angular-Compiler, that the following CSS shall be applied to Sub-Components as well. This selector will not end up in the browser, as the browser wouldn't know it!

Your global theme file is probably included directly in your html like this `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path/to/global/theme.css">` and doesn't know anything about angular (even though it's probably SASS/SCSS-compiled). Just use plain old CSS here (or SASS/SCSS if you're using the default Angular CLI). You may simply omit the  `::ng-deep` selector here, as your global theme is applied globally anyway.